Is the expression POV “Point of view” misused on social media?
According to the the following site:

Everyone knows that “POV” is short for “point of view” to represent a first-person perspective but teens also use it in the second-person to strengthen their opinions, both on social media and in verbal dialogue.

(Today.com)
The acronym POV is now very (possibly too much) widely used on social media, generally to introduce funny situations which, to use an
“obsolete”  term, they could be better described as gags.
Now,  my question is: is the expression   “Point of view” actually misused on social media? And is it actually undergoing a semantic shift? Or am I missing something?

You're going to have to give an actual example, I think I know what you are referring to. Which sites  do you see the POV being used this way?

Know Your Meme is a useful reference for this kind of thing.

As a general observation I would strongly advise against using any such abbreviation or texteese outside social media. For example, when posting questions anywhere on Stack Exchange. The problem lies in the statement  Everyone knows that “POV” is short for “point of view”. Not everyone knows this, particularly over on ELL, and some of the native English speakers are not necessarily avid social media users either. So when posting questions here and on ELL, please stick to plain English without "everyone knows" abbreviations.

@PeterJennings that was a quote, not something the OP wrote. Plus, the quote itself gives a definition for precisely this thing that not everyone knows, despite "everyone" knowing it. So as far as I can tell, the OP has used no unexplained abbreviations here at all.

@terdon Note I said "As a general observation". I was NOT referring specifically to this post. It was a request that OPs refrain from using texteese at any time.

@PeterJennings - not sure what your problem is with my question. The  sourced  text is clearly highlighted and the original  source is clearly quoted. Whether you like it or not has little to do with the rules of asking questions on ELU or any other  SE site.

@Gio Again I don't have a problem with your post. Since it was mentioning an abbreviation (OK it was explained as well) I thought this would be a good place to mention that, IN GENERAL  it is not a good thing to post questions (not this one) that use abbreviations, especially texteese, since they will not be  understood by everyone.  Maybe this should be a topic for the Meta, but I suspect that site does not get read that frequently by new members.

There is a  shift at least in its connotation. As a 'technical term' it was mainly used in literature and film until recently:

"Point of view" existed long before teenagers took over TikTok and made POV a social media slang term. In literature, the point of view is the perspective from which the story is told. There are three main types of point of view that a writer can choose from to narrate a story. The first is "first person point of view," where one of the characters describes the unfolding events from their own perspective, using words like “I” or “me.” (Parade.com)

Tik-tok took this term and used it to enhance the relatability of viewers to these short videos.
Dictionary.com has a post on Tik-tok slang which says:

POV stands for point of view. On TikTok, POV is often used in videos or as a hashtag to indicate that the video is meant to be watched as if the viewer were present or the viewer is in a specific situation. While the acronym POV is not exclusive to TikTok, POV videos are a popular video format on the platform.

Example: POV: You just posted a cringe meme.


Basically, we could translate this usage in a sentence like:

Imagine yourself in this situation.

or

you surely have been/are/could be in this very situation.

Parade.com goes at greater lengths to explain this term:

Content creators on social media will use "POV" in captions or as text on a video when they want the viewer to be watching the scene from their own perspective.
These videos are meant to make the audience feel as if they are part of the scenario, watching the scene unfold through their own eyes—whether it’s a makeup tutorial, unboxing a TikTok made-me-buy-it purchase, restocking the refrigerator, getting yelled at by the boss, going on a romantic date, or openly and honestly speaking to the viewer. Some users will “act out” a scenario using the POV trend, like dueting another creator’s content or interacting with a barista at Starbucks.

This post explains that in written messages on the media, sometimes POV simply means IMO (in my opinion):

You could write on Twitter [now X], “Nothing compares to Oreos #POV” and it would mean the same thing as “IMO, Oreos are the best cookies, ever.” Because TikTok is based on video content; however, POV and IMO aren’t quite as interchangeable on that particular social media platform.

I will add one more definition from PoetryAmerica which refers to the relatable character of these videos:

POV is a frequently used term in viral social media platform TikTok that initially indicated a form of story-telling where the creator assumes a specific character role. Nowadays, the term humorously relates to any situation that stands out or is particularly relatable to the individual.


(+1) [additionally] I hear pre/teen BrE speakers use it basically as a synonym for "Suppose"

@AakashM - and that is definitely a shift!!

You hear, @AakashM? So you have heard people using this in spoken English? As in "Pee-Oh-Vee blah blah"?

@terdon 100% yes. Note that all the people I've heard it from are under 20. But they get it from youtubers who are, let's say, 'old enough to know better' :)

Now, those are interesting POV (or POVs or PsOV, depending on how one prefers to render these ‘fronted’ plurals) - both fev’s and AakashM’s.
